How does the kernel $L$ satisfy the property of extending composition products from a chain of projective kernels?
I am currently studying the product of a chain of projective kernels, and I have a specific question regarding the extension property of a kernel $L$ in this context. Below, I present the necessary setup, theorem, and part of the proof (which comes from "Introduzione ai processi stocastici" by Giorgio Letta) that I believe should illustrate how the extension property holds. However, I am struggling to see how exactly this property is satisfied by $L$.
Hypotheses and Notations
Let $((E_n, \mathcal{E}_n))_{n \geq 0}$ be a sequence of measurable spaces, and define
$$
\Omega = \prod_{n \geq 0} E_n, \quad \mathcal{A} = \bigotimes_{n \geq 0} \mathcal{E}_n.
$$
Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 0}$ denote the sequence of canonical projections of $\Omega$ onto the individual factors. For each positive integer $n$, we define
$$
F_n = \prod_{j=0}^n E_j, \quad \mathcal{F}_n = \prod_{j=0}^n \mathcal{E}_j, \quad \mathcal{G}_n = \mathcal{T}(X_0, \dots, X_n),
$$
and we denote by $\mathcal{R}_n$ the Riesz space $\mathcal{R}(\Omega, \mathcal{G}_n)$ (the measurable bounded functions from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$). Finally, we set $\mathcal{R}_\infty = \bigcup_n \mathcal{R}_n$.
Definition 1:
A chain of projective kernels adapted to the filtration $(\mathcal{G}_n)_n$ is a succession of kernels $(K_n)$ such that $K_n$ is a projective kernel from $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}_n)$ to $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}_{n+1})$. Notice that projective simply means that $K_n$ is a retraction from $\mathcal{R}_{n+1}$ to $\mathcal{R}_n:$ it is surjective and is the identity restricted to $\mathcal{R}_n.$
Definition 2:
A composition product of the chain $(K_n)_n$ is a kernel $L$ from $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}_0)$ to $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ that extends all the composition products of the form $K_0 \circ \cdots \circ K_n$. Equivalently, if $L$ satisfies
$$
L_{|\mathcal{R}_{n+1}} = K_0 \circ \cdots \circ K_n 
$$
Theorem
Under these hypotheses, let $(K_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be a chain of projective kernels, adapted to the filtration $(\mathcal{G}_n)_{n \geq 0}$. Then $(K_n)_{n \geq 1}$ admits a unique product.
Proof (Partial)
The uniqueness is immediate: in fact, two kernels, each of which is the product of the chain $(K_n)_{n \geq 0}$, operate in the same way on each element of $\mathcal{R}_\infty$, and thus they are identical (see (1.1)).
We now prove the existence. To this end, for each pair of positive integers $n, h$, we denote by $L_{n, n+h}$ the projective kernel, relative to the pair $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}_n)$, $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}_{n+h})$, defined as follows:

$L_{n,n}$ is the identity kernel relative to $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}_n)$,
For $h > 0$, $L_{n,n+h}$ is the kernel $K_n \cdots K_{n+h-1}$ (composition product of the kernels $K_j$ with $n \leq j < n+h$).

It is clear that, for strictly positive $h$, we have:
$$
L_{n, n+h} = K_n L_{n+1, n+h}.
$$
Fixing a positive integer $n$ and an element $Z$ of $\mathcal{R}_\infty$, since the kernels $K_j$ are projective, the random variables of the form $L_{n, n+h} Z$ (for $h$ such that $Z \in \mathcal{R}_{n+h}$) are all equal to a common element of $\mathcal{R}_n$. We will denote this element by $L_n Z$.
Thus, we define an application $L_n$ (linear and isotone) from $\mathcal{R}_\infty$ to $\mathcal{R}_n$. It remains to prove that $L_0$ has the Daniell extension property: in fact, thanks to (1.1), $L_0$ will then be extendable to a kernel $L$, relative to the pair $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}_0)$, $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$, which will be the desired product of the chain $(K_n)_{n \geq 0}$.
We can observe that, for each $n$,
$$
L_n Z = K_n L_{n+1} Z.
$$

Question: How does the kernel $L$ extends the compisitions products? I think it has something to do with  the identity $L_n = K_n \circ L_{n+1}$. Could someone help clarify this part of the proof? As a side note, the Daniel property is the property is the 'continuity' for monotone limits $f_k \downarrow 0$ implies $L(f_k) \downarrow 0$

The proof is from "Introduzione ai processi stocastici" by Giorgio Letta. Let me know if you need further details on the proof, or the definition of kernel, the kernels mentioned above are all markov kernels.

Notational questions: (1) I'm guessing that  $\mathcal T(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is the $\sigma$-field (on $\Omega$) generated by $X_1,\ldots, X_n$. If so, should $G_n$ be $\mathcal G_n$? (2) And then is $\mathcal R_n$  the class of bounded $\mathcal G_n$-measurable functions from $\Omega$ to $\Bbb R$?
It appears that $L$ is the infinite composition product $K_0\circ K_1\circ\cdots \circ K_n\circ K_{n+1}\circ\cdots$.
You appear to be describing something that resembles the Ionescu Tulcea theorem, slightly reformulated.

@JohnDawkins the first answer is yes. The second I have to check to be sure. I will do it in 5 hours from now.

@JohnDawkins I've checked and the answer to the second question is yes, thanks. Let me know if further clarifications are needed.
